# date and time showing wrong time

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get the date and time formatted the way i want.. The problem is even though I get the right date the time comes out incorrectly..

If I `echo $start_date` i get this result `2014-07-16T13:20:00+02:00` which has the correct time etc 
and when I `echo $start1_date` after my format the result is `11:20 Wed 16 Jul 2014` which has the time 2hrs behind.. I am using wordpress and have set settings to Johannesburg in the backend.. This date is from the timely calendar plugin. How do i get the correct time to show? Thanks guys..

```
$start_date  = $instance->get( 'start' );
$start1_date = date(' g:i D d M Y' , strtotime($start_date) );
```

Comment: `2014-07-16T13:20:00+02:00`  That `+02:00` holds the secret

Comment: It's mysterious to me why timezones are so mysterious...

Comment: you can add `7200` seconds to the result of strtotime to compensate for that

Comment: Haven't used the plugin yet, but it seems to only return the standard gmt time, which has a two hour time difference that us in SA. I suggest that you conatct the plugin author

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
date_default_timezone_set();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php